# Best Separator For URL Data

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I am using mod rewrite and have Urls like the following:
**mysite.com/forum/thread/838/1**

The numbers on the end representing the thread and page number respectively.

What I want to do is somehow split that url into two parts **"mysite.com/forum/thread"** and **"838/1"**. The first part actually points to a physical script on my site, where as the last two numbers don't and serve more as variables. So what I need is some kind of symbol that I can use to separate them.

I was thinking of using double slashes like so to separate them:
mysite.com/forum/thread**//**838/1 
However this seems to fail in mod_rewrite which stripes the extra slash from the url.

I need a better solution was thinking of :: but have heard that has problems when you use it in links needing to do ./mysite.com::abc instead of mysite.com::abc.

Comment: Couldn't you just put "838/1" in the query part of your URL, e.g. `mysite.com/forum/thread?t=838&p=1`? Or is your URL format fixed?

Comment: Why do you need a special separator? You can have mod_rewrite pick up the last parameters even if you use slash.

Comment: I don't have a query part of my url its all neat and tidy using slashes with mod rewrite.

Comment: The amount of parameters isn't fixed it could be 2 or 5 or more, thats why I need a separator.

Comment: But if the path is fixed (always example.com/x/y) it doesn't matter how many parameters there are.

Comment: The path isn't fixed either could be mysite.com/forum/thread or mysite.com/database/cars/ferrari

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separator or to even change your URLS, you can configure Apache to pass you whatever data is left over after mapping the request in the standard PATH_INFO variable.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo